# Failure to access the index of an element in a reversed list

Tags: python

I have this code that I made in order to loop through a list backwards. I need to access the index of each element in order to check if that element is `^`. However, it sends an error that say `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` for the `if` line. What can I do?

```
equation = ['5', '^', '12', '^', '12']
for i in reversed(list(enumerate(equation))):
    if equation[i] == '^':
        ...
```

Comment: `equation = ['5', '^', '12', '^', '12'][::-1]` Temp value issue !

Comment: @dsgdfg where do I put that in my code?

Comment: friend , replace `equation = ['5', '^', '12', '^', '12']` to `equation = ['5', '^', '12', '^', '12'][::-1]`

Comment: Be carefull working on data_types. if use an global function maybe this cange your data type and  index. `equation = ['5', '^', '12', '^', '12'][::-1]` then `for i in equation: ... do somathing `

Comment: got it! i also used the simple `for i in range(equation):` for the loop.

Comment: True ! Another point  : fix your data before assign to an variable. otherwise duplicate data on system RAM_Source for refix _your_data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enumerate` gives you tuples of (index, element). So your loop should look something like this:

```py
for index, element in reversed(list(enumerate(equation))):
    if element == '^':
        equation[index] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your additional call to `list` is not necessary, additionally you can simply use `len(...)` and `range(...)` as in:

```
equation = ['5', '^', '12', '^', '12']
for index in range(len(equation) - 1, -1, -1):
    if equation[index] == "^":
        print("do sth.")
```

Or

```
for index, value in enumerate(reversed(equation)):
    if value == "^":
        print("sth.")
```